# Euler's constant is a Rational or Irrational number?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I know that this problem has been one of the challenge of the modern mathematicians, but I don't know if it Is already solved.
Thanks!

Comment: It is still unknown.

Comment: From wikipedia: if $\gamma$ is rational, its denominator must be greater than $10^{242080}$.

Comment: Which Euler's constant?  $e=2.71828\ldots$ is known to be irrational and $\gamma=0.57721\ldots$ is unknown

Comment: It avoids confusion to refer to $\gamma$ as the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0310/0310404.pdf. Am not sure if the claimed "proof" is correct.